# Get parameter from jax-ws web service

Tags: web-services, parameters, web.xml

I would like retrieve String parameter from a file in a web service (jax-ws). I've see that I can't read parameters from web.xml using FacesContext.
This code don't work:

*fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String fileOpzionali = fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("fileOpzionali");*
Suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a corresponding entry like this in your web.xml:

```
    <context-param>
       <param-name>fileOpzionali</param-name>
       <param-value>VALUE</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

?

Comment: @idarios then it should work I think.  Try getting the ServletRequest  and getting the parameter that way e.g. request.getSession().getServletContext()...